# Adding an equation for a semilog trendline

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have semi-log data to which I've fitted a trendline, but I need to figure out how to add the equation to match. Below is an example, without any of the attempts to include a label. I've tried various iterations of z[0] in a text box, but it's clear the result is incorrect. Included in the code is my latest attempt, but the result is incorrect. It's a semi-log plot, a linear equation doesn't make sense. But I'm unsure how to do an exponential equation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 100
np.random.seed(1)
x = np.zeros(n)
y = np.linspace(1, 10000, n)
rand = np.random.randn(n)
for ii in range(1, n):
    x[ii] = rand[ii] * 10 + float(ii)  # Some noise in the x values
    y[ii] = 10 ** (float(ii) / 10.0)  # Create semi-log linear data

plt.scatter(x, y)
z = np.polyfit(x, np.log10(y), 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x, 10**p(x), "g--")
plt.yscale('log')

props3 = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=1)
textStr1 = "y = %.3fx + %.3f" % (10**(z[0]), 10**(z[1]))
plt.text(0.05, 0.95, textStr1, fontsize=10, transform=plt.gca().transAxes,
         verticalalignment='top', bbox=props3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, equivalent options are to change the first part of `textStr1` to either `"$log_{10}(y) = %.3fx + %.3f$"` (expressing *x* in terms of *log10(y)*), or equivalently to `"$y = 10^{%.3fx + %.3f}$"`. The `"$...$"` format allows you to specify Latex-style equations.